Send notification when eks cluster stays more than 5 hours
I am creating multiple eks clusters in aws and deleting them after 4 hours using pipeline. Sometimes clusters are not deleting So, I need some ideas or suggestions on below cases,
If any EKS clusters are stay for 5 hours, I should get an alert or notifications whatever.

I got some ideas like, lambda script(last solution) to implement But I wanted to know do we have any other options to implement this. Your response would be very helpful..
